# Is it possible to create swift extension of Core Data Entity developed manually in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I am having developed project with core data. Now this core data files are added manually in objective C.

There is a property named size which is NSNumber.
I need to create swift extension of this Entity to implement the protocol, which has same variable "size" but as Int64

```
extension TestEntity: Item {
    var size: Int64
}
```

I tried adding extension before above code to convert NSNumber to Int64

```
extension TestEntity: Item {
    @NSManaged public var size: Int64
}
```

But then too it shows an error - "Type TestEntity does not conform to the protocol Item"

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done. In such case it advicable to remove the property added in extension from Objective C file. Or convert entire objective c files related to core data to swift.